# Can I form a direct URL to a particular Google account for which Gmail is disabled?

Tags: query-string, google-account

This existing question https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18959/can-i-form-a-direct-url-to-a-particular-gmail-account is close to what I need, except that I don't want to go into Gmail since email is disabled for the institutional account I am using. I want to log into some Google App - ideally Google Classroom, second choice Google Drive - but I'll take any alternative to Gmail if it shows it can be done (sorry I don't have a full list of enabled Apps for my institutional account).

This suggestion from Eivind Eklund works when Gmail is available

https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&Email=example@domain.com&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/u/example@domain.com/

by which I mean it gets me into my Gmail with my personal account, and with my institutional account I get "We are sorry, but you do not have access to Email. Please contact your Organisation Administrator for access."

So, is there a URL that I can pre-populate with an account to get into a service other than Gmail? I thought perhaps if I changed service=mail to service=drive, and Email= to Account= then it might work, but this produces "The requested URL was not found on this server. That’s all we know." I could be guessing all day - I can find no documentation of what the alternative parameters might be. Can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

D'oh! My colleague suggested "well let's give service=classroom a try". We then went into a particular class and copied the query string, so we can now generate direct URLs for each student (who likely won't know their ID) per class

https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=classroom&passive=true&Email=MY_INSTITUTIONAL_ID&continue=https://classroom.google.com/c/Mzk3MTAzNzk2MDVa