# Link to SSO App from external site when user is signed into multiple Google Identities

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, identity, google-workspace

Trying to link to GSuite SAML Apps from an external site (intranet).

If the user is not logged in to any Google Identities, or only logged in to the GSuite Organization's Identity, everything works.

If they are logged into some other Google Identity (their personal Gmail), there is a 404 error. The resolution is to ask the user to sign out of their personal account in order for the SAML App link to work, which is undesirable.

Link I'm using is:

```
https://www.google.com/a/my-gsuiteorg.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fapis.google.com%2Fadditnow%2Fl%3Fapplicationid%3D000000000000%26__ls%3Dogb%26__lu%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fapp.thirdpartyapp.com%252Flogin%253Fpartner_uid%253Dgoogle%0000cid%253Dpar_google_gam_launch_co-
```

Comment: Similar question, but different resolution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59051660/can-i-form-a-direct-url-to-a-particular-google-account-for-which-gmail-is-disabl

Answer (score 0):

Discovered the solution after stumbling upon this post: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/97952

By adding the "Email" parameter to specify a user to log in as, and then switching the domain to accounts.google.com, now the URL will take a user to log in for the correct corporate Gsuite Domain, and continue after with a redirect to the SAML App seamlessly.

If they're logged into multiple Google Accounts, the redirect from the SAML App's OAuth will asks them to select an Account, which is totally fine, and better than that a 404 error.

```
https://accounts.google.com/a/my-gsuiteorg.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&Email=example@my-gsuiteorg.com&continue=**SAMLAPPURL_FROM_GSUITE_LAUNCHER**
```